# CPLEX OPL: Force a set of decision variables to be equal

Tags: constraints, cplex, ibm-ilog-opl

Any smarter way to force a set of decision variables to be equal?

(If not feel free to use the solution)

### Declarations

Given the following set:

```
ID1     | ID2
------- | -------
A       | AA
B       | AA
C       | BB
C       | AA
C       | CC
D       | CC
```

e.g. initialized in OPL by

```
//Set ID
tuple ObjectID{
    string ID1;
    string ID2;
    }
{ObjectID} ID = {
    <"A", "AA">,
    <"B", "AA">,
    <"C", "BB">,
    <"C", "AA">,
    <"C", "CC">,
    <"D", "CC">,
    };
```

And a decision variable *x[ID]*
to be declared in OPL as

```
dvar int+ x[ID]
```

### The Problem

**The decision variable *x[ID]* should be equal if ID1 is equal for all ID2.**

*Example:*

```
x[<"C", "BB">] == x[<"C", "AA">] == x[<"C", "CC">]
```

### Current solution

Pairwise comparison of all dvar's with identical ID1 and different ID2.

```
forall(
   id_1 in ID, id_2 in ID:
      id_1.ID1 == id_2.ID1 &&
      id_1.ID2 != id_2.ID2
   )
x[id_1] == x[id_2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first improvement would be to use ordered to divide by 2 the number of equality constraints:

```
forall(ordered id_1,id_2 in ID :id_1.ID1 == id_2.ID1 )
     x[id_1] == x[id_2];
```

and second improvement could be to move from (n-1)*n/2 constraints to (n-1) constraints

```
//Set ID
tuple ObjectID{
    string ID1;
    string ID2;
    }
{ObjectID} ID = {
    <"A", "AA">,
    <"B", "AA">,
    <"C", "BB">,
    <"C", "AA">,
    <"C", "CC">,
    <"D", "CC">
    };

dvar int+ x[ID];

{string} Id1s={i.ID1 | i in ID};
{string} Id2PerId1[id1 in Id1s]={i.ID2 | i in ID : i.ID1==id1};



subject to
{


forall(id1 in Id1s) forall(id2 in Id2PerId1[id1] diff     {last(Id2PerId1[id1])})
   x[<id1,id2>] == x[<id1,next(Id2PerId1[id1],id2)>];


  }
```

`

Comment: Thanks Alex - that improved the speed a bit!